# unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, numpy, math, data-science

when running the code have an error like that

> ```
> unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'
> ```

if I delete this part

```py
Total = Total* exp
    Total = 1-Total
    possition = possition + 1
```

have an error like this

> ```
> IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4
> ```

Code :

```py
import random

def getsys():
    row = ''
    for i in range(0 , 8):
        randintt = str(random.randint(0 , 4))
        row += randintt
    return row


def getx():
    x = []
    for i in range(0,14):
        mysys = getsys()
        x.append(mysys)

    return x 

y = getx()
print (y)
```

```py
import initialsys
import numpy as np

R = np.array([[0.90 , 0.93,0.91 , 0.95],
               [0.95 , 0.94, 0.93, 0],
               [0.85 , 0.90 , 0.87 , 0.92],
               [0.83 , 0.87 , 0.85 , 0 ],
               [0.94 , 0.93 , 0.95 , 0],
               [0.99 , 0.98 , 0.97 , 0.96],
               [0.91 , 0.92 , 0.94 , 0],
               [0.81 , 0.90 , 0.91 , 0],
               [0.97 , 0.99 , 0.96 , 0.91],
               [0.83 , 0.85 , 0.90 , 0],
               [0.94 , 0.95 , 0.96 , 0],
               [0.79 , 0.82 , 0.85 , 0.90],
               [0.98 , 0.99 , 0.97 , 0],
               [0.85 , 0.92 , 0.95 , 0.99]
              ])

def expression(r ,possition , char ):
    exp = 1-r[possition , int(char)]


x = initialsys.getx()
possition = 0
Total = 1
Total = float(Total)
char = ""
for row in x :
    for char in row :
        if char!= 0 :
            exp = expression(R , possition , char)
            Total = Total* exp
    Total = 1-Total
    possition = possition + 1
```

Comment: You don't have `return` in `expression`, so it returns default `None`.

Comment: The function `def expression` does not return the value of `exp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `def expression(r ,possition , char )` doesn't return anything.

You should write it like this :

```
def expression(r ,possition , char ):
    return 1-r[possition , int(char)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of changes.

- You are missing the `return` statement in `expression`
- `random.randint(0 , 4)` should be `random.randint(0 , 3)`

**Ex:**

```
def expression(r ,possition , char ):
    exp = 1-r[possition , int(char)]
    return exp
```

---

```
def getsys():
    row = ''
    for i in range(0 , 8):
        randintt = str(random.randint(0 , 3))
        row += randintt
    return row
```

Comment: See this link in order to understand the notion of `scope` : https://pythonspot.com/scope/

Comment: @Rakesh I changed 4 to 3 but IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4 error still have

Answer (score 0):

I changed 4 to 3 but IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4 error still have